# how to delete facebook achievement?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have register some achievement in my app.
now,I want to delete some one.
The facebook document said that use HTTP DELETE request to /APP_ID/achievements,but I have always get 400 bad request.

help!
how to delete!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the App Access token? It should be working, if you're sure you have the app access token and it's not allowing you to remove the achievement it may be a bug in the API - file it with repro steps in the [bug tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)